# How to run U-SQL for all the files in a folder using parameters from ADF?

Tags: azure-data-factory, u-sql

Can't pass the "in" parameter to U-SQL to use all the files in the folder.

in my ADF pipeline, I have the following parameters settings:

```
"parameters": {
    "in": "$$Text.Format('stag/input/{0:yyyy}/{0:MM}/{0:dd}/*.csv', SliceStart)",
    "out": "$$Text.Format('stag/output/{0:yyyy}/{0:MM}/{0:dd}/summary.csv"
}
```

And the U-SQL script trys to extract from:

```
@couponlog =
    EXTRACT 
    Id int,
    [Other columns here]
FROM @in
USING Extractors.Csv(skipFirstNRows:1);
```

But I get file not found during execution.
The files exists in the data lake but I don't know the correct syntax to pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure there are many ways to solve the issue, but what I found is that instead of passing a parameter from the ADF pipeline, it is easier to use virtual columns. in my case **v_date**

```
@couponlog =
    EXTRACT 
    Id int,
    [Other columns here],
    v_date DateTime
FROM "stag/input/{v_date:yyyy}/{v_date:MM}/{v_date:dd}/{*}.csv"
USING Extractors.Csv(skipFirstNRows:1);
```

With this the U-SQL scrip found all the files

Comment: This is the right way to parameterize your file set. And you can add a subsequent `WHERE` clause to add additional parameters and constraints on the `v_date` column that can be used to restrict the extraction.

Comment: Using * in the virtual column names has now been deprecated. Now just use your braces but with a name for the column. For example {FileName}. Without the *.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using dates inputted by ADF with no trouble. I pass in just the date portion and then format it within USQL:

```
"parameters": {
  "in": "$$Text.Format('{0:yyyy}/{0:MM}/{0:dd}/', SliceStart)"
}
```

Then in USQL:

```
DECLARE @inputPath = "path/to/file/" + @in + "{*}.csv";
DECLARE @outputPath = "path/to/file/" + @in + "output.csv";
```

Those variables then get used in the script as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I use this input parameter in ADF to read all the files from a folder with a virtual column (file) to retrieve the name of the file

```
"parameters": {
    "in": "$$Text.Format('storage/folder/{0:yyyy}-{0:MM}/{1}.csv', SliceStart, '{file:*}')",
    "out": "$$Text.Format('otherFolder/{0:yyyy}-{0:MM}/result.txt', SliceStart)"
}
```

The related U-SQL

```
@sales =
    EXTRACT column1 string,
            column2 decimal,
            file string
    FROM @in
    USING Extractors.Csv(silent : true);
```